# easiest way to get only folder names with .zip in php

Tags: php, regex, php-ziparchive

I have seen a few example on the web but they seem pretty messy. I am looking for a nice and clean way to say, get me only the files/folders that have `.zip` on them. What I have so far is:

```
    foreach(scandir(__DIR__) as $files) {
        var_dump($files);
    }
```

What I wonder is is if I need pre match or if the ZipArchive class has any functions that state "return only files with `.zip`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you, you can use `glob()`:

```
<?php

    foreach (glob("*.zip") as $filename) {
        echo $filename . "<br />";
    }

?>
```

possible Output:

```
test - Kopie.zip
test.zip
test2.zip
```

For more information about `glob()` see the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Comment: `glob`s documentation doesn't state that it looks in the current directory (and the current directory only). hence why I went with `scandir(__DIR)))` Do you know if it is strictly related to the directory you run `glob` in?

Comment: @TheWebs Yes it is strictly related to the directory you run glob in, otherwise you have to set the path to it! So if you have other files in sub dir's they don't get displayed! (You can test that yourself)